# Ranking system algorithm in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I am trying to create a feedback or ranking system in node.js. Below is the scenario which i am trying to create. I have successfully create one part of it but i am not sure about the other part.

Scenario:
A user has an account and on this account, he can sell clothing items. Now when some one buys an item, the buyer will give feedback based on his experience. The feedback will both effect that particular clothing items rating as well as user's overall rating.

So if a user has 3 different items to sell and people buy it, how can i implement a system which tells the overall rating for a user.

Comment: What have you done already?

Comment: You can start by giving it *some* thought first.

Comment: I actually spent some time before coming here. Taking the average just didn't feel right to me that's why i came here. Anyways another guy has posted the answer which is sufficient enough to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple solution is to just average the ratings of those 3 different items

**Example**

```
userRating = []
prod1Rating = []
prod2Rating = []
prod3Rating = []

// Someone buys prod1 and gives it a 3 star
prod1Rating.push(3)
userRating.push(3)

// Someone buys prod2 and gives it a 4 star
prod2Rating.push(4)
userRating.push(4)

// Someone buys prod3 and gives it a 4 star
prod3Rating.push(4)
userRating.push(4)
```

Now your arrays will look like :

```
userRating = [3,4,4]
prod1Rating = [3]
prod2Rating = [4]
prod3Rating = [4]
```

So to get the users rating just average all the values in the array in this case that will be `3.66`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was just confused if this is the right way and you have removed my doubt. Thanks